# Facing Login Timeout issues in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

SSIS jobs are getting failed frequently with the below error message. Although it restarts and runs successfully in the next run, SSIS jobs are getting failed sporadically in the subsequent runs. These issues were happening after our SQL Server was patched with KB4338824 and KB4338815 updates. Any help?

> Error: 2018-07-19 23:38:22.52    Code: 0xC0202009    Source:
>   ParallelExport Connection manager "XXXXConnectionString"
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult:
>   0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired". End Error Error:
>   2018-07-19 23:38:22.52    Code: 0xC00291EC    Source: Get Export List
>   to Process Execute SQL Task    Description: Failed to acquire
>   connection "XXXXConnectionString". Connection may not be configured
>   correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection. End Error

Comment: You'll need to check the SQL Server error log and machine event logs for more details, if there are any. SSIS isn't going to get any more details beyond the fact that logging in took too long, for whatever reason. This could be due to a network issue or Kerberos (if using integrated authentication).

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout?  If that fixes it you can narrow down the troubleshooting.